# Interaction of smart contract with mobile wallet/ wallet connect

Tags: dapps, smart-contract-wallets, walletconnect, mobile-wallet

I have a dapp that interacts with a smart contract using metamask through brownser and I would like to be able to interact with this smart contract through a mobile wallet using wallet connect.

I can already connect to the mobile wallet but I don't know how to interact with the smart contract.

I am interacting with the smart contract through the metamask extension by this way:

```
contract.methods.mint(arg).send({from : 0x34s..., 
value: xxxx })
```

And it already opens a request to the owner of the connected account in metamask extension.

But I would like to know how I can interact with this function using mobile wallets by wallet connect.

I already have the mobile wallet user connected, I just don't know how to interact with this smart contract function and request the value from the mobile user connected.

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you connected in mobile using the [WC web3 connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/web3-provider)? If you are, then all interactions should be the same, and should open the mobile MM for approval. If you are using this connector - what happens when you issue a `mint` tx?

Comment: yes, I am connected yes to the wc web connector. but I don't know how I passed the "mint" function in sendTransaction.

Comment: What do you mean? What happens when you do it exactly like how you would do it with normal Metamask? Like what you wrote in the original question

Answer (score 0):

you could just do simply do this :)

`const instance =   new ethers.Contract( 'testERc20Address', testAbi, this.modal.getSigner());`

`const resp=await result.transfer('sometestAddresstoTransfer',22);`

"this.modal.getSigner()"  this should bee the signer, just the pass the signer in base of what you use the wagmi or the ether version.

docs here :
https://docs.walletconnect.com/web3modal/about